# Is it possible to convert a debug assembly into a release assembly?

Tags: .net, dll, release-mode, debug-mode

Given a source assembly (dll) that is in debug mode, is there a way to generate a release mode assembly?

Note:  This question stems from the need to deploy a dll to production in release mode for a dll in which we no longer have the source code, just a dll in debug mode.

Comment: Given that there could be code that uses `#if` to compile different code in for debug and release, no. But you should know that source better than anyone else - is there anything from the debug build you specifically don't want in the release build?

Comment: @JonSkeet - There is nothing that I would want omitted from the source code, no.  No use of #if

Comment: In that case, Ðаn's answer is probably appropriate - it's likely to just be optimization, basically. Is this performance critical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer to your direct question is "no."  This is because there may be `#if DEBUG`s in the original C# code that are no longer present in the compiled MSIL.

Long answer part A) for the most part, it shouldn't matter a whole lot, certainly not to the degree is does with C or C++ where there are different run-time libraries for debug vs. release.  Perhaps the biggest downside is that you'd be missing release optimization (and/or the overhead of extra debug-only code).

Longer answer part B) if you **really** needed something in release mode (e.g., for optimization), you could *try* using a decompiler to get some C# code back and re-compile that in release mode.